# How to export abstract class using Angular 2 RC6 and NgModule

Tags: angular

Angular 2 RC6 problem !!!

So imagine the situation where we have a standard class such as...

```
export abstract class FooBase {}
```

and then we want to export this class to be used by other modules within an Angular 2 RC6 web app, the NgModule code may look like this...

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [FooBase],
    exports: [FooBase],
    imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class OurModule {}
```

Unfortunately when running this inside chrome it returns with...

> Unexpected value 'FooBase' exported from module 'OurModule'

This base class is used to extend an existing class inside another module, simple stuff really, what am I doing wrong here !!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use `NgModule` `imports`, `exports`, `declarations` for imports and exports of class declarations. `@NgModule` is only for components, directives, pipes and services.

Just use normal TypeScript imports and exports.